# MySQL said: Documentation #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to move my eCommerce website I created my self from a WAMPSERVER localhost to my online host.
In order to move the database(which was working perfectly on my localhos), I export it as an sql file,Then I created a new database in my online server to import the database sql file.
The problem I get after hit import is this :

ErrorSQL query:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--
CREATE TABLE  `users` (

 `UserID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'To Identify User',
 `Username` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'Username To Login',
 `Password` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'Password To Login',
 `Email` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'User Email',
 `FullName` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'User Full name',
 `GroupID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT
);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 14

### What is the problem ?

UPDATE : 
The problem solved after adding the comment, but I'm getting another error messages like this :

```
    Error
SQL query:

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE  `users` MODIFY  `UserID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
AUTO_INCREMENT =9 COMMENT  'To Identify User';


MySQL said: Documentation

#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key
```

Comment: You seem to add a comment but did not provide the text for it.

Comment: `COMMENT` what? Either remove it, or add an actual comment.

Comment: Yes I think @Jens is right. Also if you are saying that query is not working for you on staging. you should check for the version difference of MYSQL and PHP on your local WAMP server and the hosting server. Some break update in Mysql might breaks the code sometimes.

Comment: The error message seems very clear: If you want to make `UserID` an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, you have to define it as a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is in the last line you need to set a COMMENT 'your comment ' or completely remove COMMENT

```
 CREATE TABLE  `users` (

 `UserID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'To Identify User',
 `Username` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'Username To Login',
 `Password` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'Password To Login',
 `Email` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'User Email',
 `FullName` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'User Full name',
 `GroupID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT 'group id'
);
```

Comment: @Yaser AlAzm did this answer solve your problem ?

Comment: Thank you, It solved it.

Comment: you are welcome Yaser glad t help u :)

Comment: But actually I'm getting another errors like the one I just added to the main question . You can check the updated part in the question.

Comment: @YaserAlAzem you want to make the GroupID AUTO_INCREMENT ???

Comment: not at all, GroupID is set by the admin, and I just see the userId linked in the error message. no mention to the GroupID in the error message!

Comment: @YaserAlAzem drop the table completely and add this to the first line after the comment  `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` and run your query again on phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

You miss the comment for the Last column. Add it

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--
CREATE TABLE  `users` (

 `UserID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'To Identify User',
 `Username` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'Username To Login',
 `Password` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'Password To Login',
 `Email` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'User Email',
 `FullName` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'User Full name',
 `GroupID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT ''
);
```

or if you do not need it, remove the `COMMENT` keyword:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--
CREATE TABLE  `users` (

 `UserID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'To Identify User',
 `Username` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'Username To Login',
 `Password` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'Password To Login',
 `Email` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'User Email',
 `FullName` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'User Full name',
 `GroupID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0'
);
```

UPADTE:

To alter the autoincrement you have to add a primary key. Complete syntax looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE  `users` (

 `UserID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'To Identify User',
 `Username` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'Username To Login',
 `Password` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'Password To Login',
 `Email` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'User Email',
 `FullName` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT  'User Full name',
 `GroupID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
PRIMARY Key (UserID)
);

 ALTER TABLE users MODIFY UserID INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'To Identify User';
 ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=9
```

To test this see my [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8725f)

Comment: Thank you I already added the comment, but actually I'm getting another errors like the one I just added to the main question . You can check the updated part in the question.

Comment: I already removed it, it also still the same error message.

Comment: @YaserAlAzem See my updated answer